# Is it possible to include Rails actionpack in a separate require statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require, actionpack

I have an API controller that does not inherit from Application controller.  I'm trying to include the respond_to method and get a method undefined error....So then I required actionpack at the top like below:

```
require 'actionpack'

class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::ApiController
  version 1

  doorkeeper_for :all
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with current_user.as_json(except: :password_digest)
  end
end
```

and I got the following:

*LoadError (cannot load such file -- actionpack):
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:1:in `'*

I already have *gem 'actionpack'* in my Gemfile as well as Rails 4.1.2 (this is part of a Rails 4 application)

Answer (score 6):

bah, I just realized I didn't add the underscore as in:

```rb
require 'action_pack'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to [mixin](http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/07/30/ruby-class-module-mixins/) an action_pack module into your ApiController. For this you need `include` not `require`. If you're in Rails action_pack is already loaded, if not and you've bundled the action_pack gem then yea require it. Then you need to:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::ApiController
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
```

The `ActionController::MimeResponds` module will be mixed into your controller and now the `respond_to` method will be available to it.

[Read the source, Luke](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bfc34fc0050ce61650701676dd45553aa82214c0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb)